# Unable to compile Android Source code (cloned from Git)

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm facing a very serious problem. I've cloned a git repository from https://android.googlesource.com and can successfully import a project in eclipse (say, platform/packages/apps/Contacts). But, the project shows a large number of errors due to Private Android classes being referred by the source code. I need to have a compiled version of the source code by any means.

Does any one have an idea on how to solve this issue? Any kind of help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

1) Clean your project.

2) Check your projects build target. Right click your project , go to properties > Android and make sure the appropriate android API is checked.

3) If the imported project uses Google APIs, make sure you have Google APIs installed and your  project build target is set to it.

Comment: In eclipse, Go to Window > Show view > problems. and you will see the exact errors.

Comment: Errors are there because of Android's private classes being imported. I've even attached the correct android source with android.jar, still it's the same

Comment: Can you at least post an example of one of those imports